# Django: Help overwriting a model's save() method to auto populate a CharField based on a function on object creation

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model (Meal) with several many to many fields (proteins, carbohydrates and fats), which I recently added a 'name' CharField to.  I wanted to allow the user to enter a name for a meal, but if they do not enter a name, I want the name to be populated automatically based on the function definitions I have in the model which just concatenate the names of the foods in one string.  I was trying to follow this [guide](https://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/nov/02/django-tips-auto-populated-fields/).

Now, if the Meal already exists, what I have actually works fine.  However, if it does not exist, the food_name for each item appears not to have saved yet because they are empty.  I put the `super(Meal,self).save()` statement before my `if not self.name:` statement in the hopes that this would save the object to the database so that the food_names could then be retrieved, but it does not work and instead when I do save the name is saved as '(0)'.  What I am looking for the name to populate via the `__str__` function as 'Pork Tenderloin, Spinach (steamed/boiled), Potato (Red, medium) (3)', for example.

Also, if I don't call `super(Meal,self).save()` before the if statement, I actually get a 'maximum recursion depth exceeded' error.

Can anyone tell me if there is a way to auto populate this name field based on my function definition on object creation as I've described?

I am new to Django, and have limited experience with Python, so thank you very much for any help you can provide.

Here is my model:

```
class Meal(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Meal Plan Meals'

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)
    proteins = models.ManyToManyField(to="Food", limit_choices_to={'food_type': 'P'},blank=True,related_name='food_proteins')
    carbohydrates = models.ManyToManyField(to="Food", limit_choices_to={'food_type': 'C'}, blank=True, related_name='food_carbohydrates')
    fats = models.ManyToManyField(to="Food",  limit_choices_to={'food_type': 'F'}, blank=True, related_name='food_fats')

    def all_foods(self):
       return list(self.proteins.all())+list(self.carbohydrates.all())+list(self.fats.all())

    def __str__(self):
        return ', '.join(map(lambda x: x.food_name, self.all_foods()))+f' ({len(self.all_foods())})'

    def save(self):
        super(Meal,self).save()
        if not self.name:
            self.name = self.__str__()
            self.save()
```

Edit:

The main reason I am trying to do this is because I need to be able to sort on the string returned by the `__str__` method in my Meal model, but after posting another question on stack overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58963778/django-admin-custom-ordering-according-to-concatenated-charfields-of-a-related) I found out that I believe this is not possible.  It seems you can only sort on fields in your model, and so I chose instead to add a name field (where I additionally decided that I could allow the user to name the meal something if they wanted to instead of letting it be auto populated). Currently when there are many meals it is impossible to find any single one because the ordering is based on pk's which appears totally random in terms of the names of the items and makes it virtually unusable.  Here is a picture for reference:

[image: meal list]

Currently, I create meal objects through the django admin ui only.  Here is the code for my MealAdmin in admin.py:

```
class MealAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Meal
    save_as = True
    #search bar - search by food name
    search_fields = ['name','proteins__food_name','carbohydrates__food_name','fats__food_name',]
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'fields': ('name', 'proteins', 'carbohydrates', 'fats',),
            'description': "Note: If you do not choose a name for your meal the meal will be named according to all of the foods it contains. Ex: 'Chicken Breast,Rice (white) (cooked),Avocado'"
        }),
    )
```

and a picture for reference:

[image]

So, if anyone has any idea how to cause the save function to auto-populate the name field on creation based on my `__str__` function - or any other work around, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: considering if you don't change m2m fields later , in your save method after you check that name attribute is null also check if there is any proteins,carbs,fat assigned to this object as well

Comment: I added `print(list(self.carbohydrates.all()))` before the if statement (and likewise did this for proteins and fats) and the output is `[]`.  So, no, no objects have been saved/assigned and I'm not sure why.  How can I make them save to the database so I can then call my function on them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want something to happen when creating a new instance through `admin` interface, the way to do is different than just overriding your model `save` method: you have to override the `save_model` method in your `admin` declaration.

You could try something like below:

```py
# admin.py
class MealAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):        
        obj.save()
        form.save_m2m()
        # your custom stuff goes here
        if not obj.name:
            obj.name = obj.__str__()
            obj.save()
```

Comment: Unfortunately this saves the name as `(0)`.  Which is the same problem I was having at the start when trying to override the save method for my Meal model.  :(  I very much appreciate your help!  Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Have you deleted the custom `save` method of yours in your model before trying the admin proposal? Because if not, `name` could have already been populated with (0), thus the `if not obj.name` would never been checked. Also, you should add a default value for `name`, such as `default=''`

Comment: Yes i did delete the custom save method before implementing this.  :(  What does adding a default value of an empty string here gain me (especially since if left blank I want it to be filled with what my function returns)?

Comment: It seems that the initial `obj.save` call is not actually saving  the object to the database, and I do not understand why.  This seems to happen both in your suggested code edit and my original attempt at overriding the save method (where I initially called `super(Meal,self).save()`)

Comment: If I add `if not obj.name and (obj.proteins.all() or obj.fats.all() or obj.carbohydrates.all()):` then the name is left blank on clicking save, and clicking on the object and clicking save a SECOND time does the trick... the name is populated as I wanted... so this seems to jive with my above statement that I'm not sure `obj.save` is saving to the database. Obviously I do not want to have to save once, click on the object, and save again for the desired effect though...

Comment: Yeah saving to database properly can be a nightmare. I don't get why this is not working here. I will update my proposal with a new solution based on signals!

Comment: I will try to investigate on why obj is not being really saved to db (because this is what happens, and I'm interested in why). To answer one of your comments, to me it is a good practice to always set a default value for any field of an object. It has avoided me some undesirable side effects!

Comment: I updated my answer, can you try saving manually the `m2m` fields by doing `form.save_m2m()`? (no guarantee though). I've got another idea yet

Comment: Oh my GOSH that finally worked!!!  Thank you so much!!!  I had looked at the form.save_m2m earlier, but I had no idea how to get access to the form instance that django admin uses.  What I don't get is that I read that many to many fields aren't saved when you say commit=false.  It did not say that happens ordinarily though. (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method)

Comment: Great!! Actually `save_m2m` can be called not only when `commit=False`, but you're right the documentation is not very explicit. I proposed a modification of my answer using signals if you want to give it a try too (would be curious to know if it works!). Thanks for the question, I learned a lot while helping you too! All the best!

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `save` signal to do your custom stuff when creating your object. For instance:

```py
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

class Meal(models.Model):

    # [...]

    @classmethod
    def update_name(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if not cls.name:
            cls.name = self.__str__()
            cls.save()

post_save.connect(Meal.update_name, sender=Meal)
```

However, this will be called whenever `save` is being called, not only at creation time (since there is not a `post_create` signal). Not a big issue, but not 100% satisfying. Hope this one will work!

---

## EDIT

Another try with signals, but with `m2m_changed` this time. We will try to call `update_name` each time one of the `m2m` fields has been updated, because the issue seems to be that those fields being saved independantly from `Meal` model, everything is asynchronous thus updated data of those fields are not available when needed.

```py
from django.db.models.signals import m2m_changed

class Meal(models.Model):

    # [...]

    @classmethod
    def update_name(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if not cls.name:
            cls.name = self.__str__()
            cls.save()

m2m_changed.connect(Meal.update_name, sender=Meal.proteins.through)
m2m_changed.connect(Meal.update_name, sender=Meal.carbohydrates.through)
m2m_changed.connect(Meal.update_name, sender=Meal.fats.through)
```

With this solution, each time one of those `m2m` field is updated, name will be updated too thanks to `update_name` method.

Source : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/signals/#m2m-changed

Comment: I had actually tried implementing this earlier and just assumed I was doing it wrong, but I actually get the same error now which says: `post_save.connect(Meal.update_name, sender=Meal)
NameError: name 'Meal' is not defined`. What am I doing wrong? (Meal is the name of my model and it is inside of this that I put this function)

Comment: Stupid question: the `post_save.connect...` is located after the definition of your `Meal` model?

Comment: Stupid answer - No it wasn't.  Oops.  Thanks!  But on fixing that I realized that self is not actually passed to the update_name function.  I am not sure what it should be?  I tried to replace it with sender and that did not work... and I feel a little like a monkey poking at something with a stick to see how it works...

Comment: My mistake! I updated my answer. Actually `cls` or `self` is the same thing, it is just a convention regarding you are defining a static method or a class method! I've got another idea if this one does not work, here coming for another answer haha

Comment: Ok, I changed self to cls, but the name field still ends up empty.  :'(

Comment: I tried this but get an error which says `TypeError: update_name() missing 1 required positional argument: 'created'`.  I'm sorry, but I'm pretty unfamiliar with signals and so I'm not sure what other argument it needs

Comment: Don't worry, it's not something I use everyday too. I updated my answer, if it still does not work, never mind you still have a working solution :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204668/discussion-between-kristen-l-and-krazymax).

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can not assign `m2m` fields if the object does not exist already (because before there is no primary key associated to your instance yet). You first need to save the object, then set a value for m2m fields. Then you can save your object and customize your `name` field. That's why you have got empty values.

Just a question, why don't you customize your `__str__` function instead? It would be (in my opinion of course!) simpler to maintain and use than override `save` base function. Something like:

```py
def __str__(self):
    if self.name: return self.name
    return ', '.join(map(lambda x: x.food_name, self.all_foods()))+f' ({len(self.all_foods())})'
```

So if there is a custom `name` value set by user, fine you will use that; if not, you will return the whole thing. I am never comfortable in overriding default `save` functions actually when you can do otherwise!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately this will not work for me (I should have mentioned and will edit my post to add this) that the reason I am doing this is because I want to sort on the name field in the modelAdmin. I actually submitted another post on stackoverflow on how to sort using methods, but found out that this is not possible. So for this same reason, I cannot use your solution either. Do you think there might be a way to save the object to create it and then update it with the name if name is empty, and have this all happen when i push the 'save' button, or something like this?

Comment: Ok, now I understand your need! :-) How are your objects created? Through some `CreateView`? Usually when I have such updates to do, first I create `my_object` instance, then I call some `my_object.custom_update()` method, then I save my instance again (especially if I have to deal with m2m fields which is the only way I know).

Comment: As of right now I only have the ability to create the objects using the django admin interface, and am trying to make do with this for the time being. So, simply just clicking the 'add meal' button in the django admin interface for the Meal objects is how I create an object.  I will edit my post to show my MealAdmin code.  Will I be able to do what you suggest given this?

Comment: Oh ok then! I will make another answer with an admin proposal, because discussion here is starting to become a bit long!